# WordPress: Add user's comment count to their User Metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I use the following code to grab a **user's total comments made on other users posts** (it excludes comments posted on the user's own posts):

```
function grab_custom_user_comments_count( $uid ){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total 
            FROM {$wpdb->comments} as c  
            JOIN {$wpdb->posts} as p ON p.ID = c.comment_post_ID 
            WHERE c.comment_approved = '1' 
            AND p.post_status ='publish'  
            AND p.post_type ='post'  
            AND p.post_author != c.user_id            
            AND c.user_id = %d";

    $comment_count_others = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $uid ) );
    return $comment_count_others;
}
$user_comment_count = grab_custom_user_comments_count( $userID );
```

Now, instead of running this code, I want to update all users' [metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) with this value. So the `$meta_value` would be the total count of comments (as seen above) and the `$meta_key` could be `custom_user_comments`.

**How do I add this metadata for all users?** And how do I make it so that the value updates whenever a user makes a comment on a different user's post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a plugin:

- to modify all user meta on plugin activation
- to check every posted comment and update if necessary

You'll have to fill the gaps using the user ID provided in each function:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SO) Comment to User Meta
 * Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25464099/1287812
 * Author: brasofilo
 */

/**
 * Modify all user meta on plugin activation
 */
register_activation_hook(   __FILE__, function() 
{
    # Security checks
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
        return;

    $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : '';
    check_admin_referer( "activate-plugin_{$plugin}" );

    # ITERATE THROUGH USERS AND UPDATE METADATA
    foreach( get_users() as $user ) 
    {
        # http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta
        #
        $user_comment_count = grab_custom_user_comments_count( $user->data->ID );
    }
});

/**
 * Update user meta on comment post
 * looks like this hook only runs for logged users, checking for that just to be safe
 *
 * @param $id           Comment ID
 * @param $comment_obj  Full comment details
 */
add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', function( $id, $comment_obj ) 
{
    # Only on backend and for logged users
    if( is_admin() || !is_user_logged_in() )
        return; 

    # CURRENT LOGGED USER
    global $user_ID;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    # POST AUTHOR
    # http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta
    #
    $user_comment_count = grab_custom_user_comments_count( $comment_obj->user_id );
    // You can compare $user_ID and $comment_obj->user_id here
}, 10, 2 );
```

The `$comment_obj` passed in `wp_insert_comment` hook contains an array like the following, and you can use `get_post( $comment_obj->comment_post_ID )` to grab information about the current post.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [comment_ID] => 36
    [comment_post_ID] => 885
    [comment_author] => nicename
    [comment_author_email] => email@mail.com
    [comment_author_url] => 
    [comment_author_IP] => 127.0.0.1
    [comment_date] => 2014-08-23 19:16:49
    [comment_date_gmt] => 2014-08-23 17:16:49
    [comment_content] => Lorem ipsum lorem
    [comment_karma] => 0
    [comment_approved] => 1
    [comment_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36 FirePHP/4Chrome
    [comment_type] => 
    [comment_parent] => 0
    [user_id] => 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If possible, I need some further clarification. Firstly, *update_usermeta* is deprecated, *update_user_meta* will need to be used. Can you please add the user ID so I can understand how it should be inserted? Also, does the value update *only* whenever the user posts a comment on **someone else's post**? So if the user posts a comment on their own post, the value doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, I copied the URL from google, correct is `update_user_meta`. I've updated the answer with some usage example and more comments to clarify your doubts.

Comment: You my friend, saved me a lot of hours of hassle, thank you SO much!